# Has and belongs to many - create nested attributes or reference existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models (lets call them Part and Assembly and say they each have a name attribute) that have a has and belongs to many association:

```
class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :part
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies
end
```

I am building an API, when i create a new Assembly with POST, i want to be able to:

- Provide Part attributes and have the the Part created (as per accepts_nested_attributes_for)
- Provide the ID of an existing Part that will be associated with my newly created Assembly model

Is this possible? Ideally I would like to be able to pass

```
{ name: "Assembly1", parts_attributes: [{ name: "Part 1" }]})
```

or

```
{ name: "Assembly1", parts_attributes: [{ id: 1 }]}
```

or some combination

```
{ name: "Assembly1", parts_attributes: [{ name: "Part 1" }, { id: 1 }]})
```

to the API but always be able to do

```
Assembly.create(params)
```

and have rails figure out whether to create a new Part or associate an existing one.

If this isn't possible, would be great to hear how I could elegantly implement in my controller. If possible I'd rather avoid having to loop over parts_attributes, and either create or find each Part, then set the parts on the newly created Assembly

**Update**

We eventually solved this by manipulating the inbound params as follows:

- For each of the parts hashes:
- If it contains an ID then we want to link it assembly - add it to an array called **part_ids** in the params
- If it does not contain an ID then add it an array called **parts_attributes**

The above would mean that when a part id is passed then that part is assumed to exist and will be linked to the assembly. If a part id is not supplied, then we assume the part should be created. Rails supplies the part_ids and parts_attributes methods that do the actual work.